# Assistance with an uninstall Batch file, possibility of running a do/for within a do/for

Tags: batch, uninstall

I am relatively new to creating batch files.
Would someone be able to assist me with me with the following:
I have a piece of software called "`ABCSoftware`", it installs on every user profile.
When new versions of the software are installed, it makes new folders ex:

```
ABCSoftware\20190102
ABCSoftware\20190505
ABCSoftware\20200221
```

Each profile folder has an uninstall.exe that cleans things up nicely.

I am trying to put together a batch file that will go through every subfolder after the `ABCSoftware\` and uninstall using the uninstall.exe

I have succeeded on getting the batch to work but it only seems to uninstall on the profile I'm running the batch on.

See below:

```
echo uninstalling same software on every profile...
for /d %%D in ("C:\Users\AceForSale\AppData\Local\ABCSoftware\*") do (
    "%%D\uninstall.exe" /uninstall /silent
)
```

This coding above works and successfully goes through my AceForSale Windows Profile and uninstalls each version but only for my profile. But there are multiple users on this machine so I can't seem to get a working wild card. I have tried "`%UserProfile%` and other wild cards but haven't been too successful.
Is it possible to do another for/do statement inside this one?

Thank you

Comment: Easiest way, if it is all on one machine, to make a scheduled task with the parameter to "run on user login" that will auto run the batch everytime a user signs in.

Comment: I am making a batch to deploy via SCCM during an uninstall so I have to use a batch file

Comment: I thing you can do it by something that need admin rights, but without it no way...

Comment: You'll need to inspect the uninstall scripts to confirm whether they'll work when run from outside the user profile. Basically, it shouldn't be difficult for your script to enumerate the various user profiles as an administrator and find and run the uninstall.bat file, but do you know that the bat file run in profile02 will uninstall ABCSoftware for profile02?